# conceptual questions about Gram-Schmidt: when does the process terminate (for linearly dependent vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

I am studying the GS procedure and was told that we can use GS to detect linear dependence of the input set. More specifically, GS will produce a basis that is of less size that the original spanning set. My question is, how do you know when to stop? If the $\mathbf{u_i}$ produced on the ith iteration is $\mathbf{0}$, then does this imply that $\mathbf{v_i}$ is redundant with the previous $\mathbf{v_i}$'s (and therefore linearly dependent)? Maybe we should check, at each iteration, that $\mathbf{u_i}$ is indeed orthogonal to the previous $\mathbf{u_i}$'s? Or is this not necessary?

If we just need to find when $\mathbf{u_i}=0$, should we stop GS right then and there and extract the basis? Or do we continue on as normal?

Thanks!

Comment: If numerics are not a concern then $u_i=0$ means $v_i$ is in the span of the previous vectors. If there are other vectors you should continue with them, there is no reason that subsequent vectors are necessarily in the span of $u_k$ for $k<i$.

Comment: So does orthogonallity to the previous ones have any relevance?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. GM always procedures an orthogonal (possibly zero) sequence.

Comment: Ah I see. So if the orthogonal vector produced is 0, we know it is redundant?

Comment: Yes (ignoring numerical error).